# Take image from bitmap and put it in string

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have `String bitmap1` that will take compressed image from `Bitmap photo`,
but the problem here and I think the `bitmap1` take image from `imageview` that view token image and not from `photo` because when I send an image to server it will send small resolution like of imageview, although I set compressing 100

```
    private void takeImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            String[] filepath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filepath, null , null , null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getColumnName(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tokenImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }

....

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
            byte[] by = bao.toByteArray();
            bitmap1 = Base64.encodeToString(by, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this-   

 Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo , 600,370, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, blob);

       String StrBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(blob.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: you can change width 370 and height - 600 parameter from Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo , 600,370, true); as per your requirement

Comment: It selected before also after uploading image to server the size of image is about 400 kb but the quality is too bad like before

Comment: Try to select high quality image and test it. M using the same code and its working fine.
You can check my image quality here - 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/SchApp/5d73871c-d78b-4898-85e3-261d845f4358_bg.JPEG

Comment: Replace code
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo , 600,370, true);
To

 Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)(bitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(bitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);